# Getting a horizontal scroll bar within a 100% div

Tags: css, scroll

I'm trying to build a quick overview that shows the upcoming calendar week.  I want it arranged horizontally so it can turn out to be quite wide if we show a full calendar week.

I've got it set up right now with an inner div with a fixed width (so that the floated "day" divs don't return below) and an outer div that's set to width: 100%.  I'd LIKE for the outer div to scroll horizontally if the page is resized so that the inner div no longer fits in it, but instead the outer div is fixed larger at the width of the inner div and the page itself scrolls.

Gah I'm not good at explaining these things... Here's a bit of code that might clear it up..

The CSS:

```css
.cal_scroller {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.cal_container {
    width: 935px;
}

.day {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 175px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

and the (simplified) structure:

```
<div class="cal_scroller">
    <div class="cal_container">
        <div class="day">Monday</div>
        <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="day">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="day">Thursday</div>
        <div class="day">Friday</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So to try again - I'd like the `cal_scroller` div always be the page width, but if the browser is resized so that the `cal_container` doesn't fit anymore I want it to scroll WITHIN the container.  I can make it all work if I set a fixed width on cal_scroller but that's obviously not the behavior I'm going for.  I'd rather not use any javascript cheats to adjust the width of the div if I don't have to.

Comment: Sorry everyone, this is my issue.  I just put the code in a standalone file and it works fine.  There's some other goofy stuff going on in my doc that's breaking this.

sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `cal_scroller` class is 100% + 20px (padding) wide. Use a margin on `cal_container` instead, like so:

```css
.cal_scroller {
    padding: 10px 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.cal_container {
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 935px;
}
```

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for a description of how the box model works (in short, the *everything* is outside the width/height of an element).

Also, block elements (like `<div>`s) are 100% width by default, making your 100% width declaration redundant.

Comment: Good catch, but removing the padding doesn't solve the issue.  The page still scrolls instead of the scroller div

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read your question very carefully, but when you have `width: 100%` and `padding`, that's generally not what you want.

`100% + 20px > 100%` - that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is your `width: 100%` rule.  `div.cal_scroller` is already a block-level element, so it'll default to filling the entire page width.  (Not to mention that padding is added on *top* of width, so you end up with that div being bigger than the page.)

Just get rid of that width rule, and you should be golden.  (I just tried myself, and it worked like a charm.)

Comment: I removed the width: 100%; and it didn't change anything.  As people have said, it's redundant, but I was hoping it would help describe what I'm trying to do (I DON'T want to set a fixed width on the scrolling div).  You got the scrolling to happen within the scroller div when the window was resized (as opposed to scrolling the entire page)??

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a lot but the simplest solution I found was adding:

```
.cal_container { white-space: nowrap; }
```

This way you don't have to give it a width at al. It just makes sure everything stays in one line.