# Have a horizontally scroll bar with a width:100% element

Tags: html, css

I have the next DIV in my website (It takes 100% in width of my page) :

```
float: left;
border: solid 2px rgb(119, 36, 98);
width: 100%;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 10px;
background-color: #eee;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

[image]
[image]

I would like to put in this div a table largest than the table displayed (and have a horizontally scroll bar if needed).

But if I do that the rule width:100% is not respected

```
float: left;
height: 250px;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 2000px;
```

[image]

Any ideas to have an element with 100% of my screen with a horizontally scroll bar ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143901/getting-a-horizontal-scroll-bar-within-a-100-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sVa7S/153/)

```
<div id="scroll">
    <img src="http://thinkingstiff.com/images/priorities.png" />
</div>


html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#scroll {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;    
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#scroll img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top; /* this prevents vertical whitespace */
}
```

Comment: The problem is that my parent div have "min-width:780px;
border-left: solid 200px #CCC;". If I use width:100% on it, an horizontally scroll bar appear to my global window

Comment: calc(100% - 220px) is now my friend